# Spark-MongoDB Connector Aggregation Pipeline error: not found: value Document

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, aggregation-framework, pipeline

I am trying to create an aggregation pipeline:

```
val rdd = MongoSpark.load(sc)
val aggregatedRdd = rdd.withPipeline(Seq(Document.parse("[{$project: {Country: 1, Region: 1, 'Unit Price': 1, 'Unit Cost': 1}}, {$match: {'Unit Price': {$gt: 500 }, 'Unit Cost': {$lt: 510}}}, {$sort: {Region: 1}}]")))
```

But I get the following error:

```
<console>:28: error: not found: value Document
```

Comment: Missing some imports?

Comment: It is possible but having followed the documentation I didn't see any required imports.

Comment: `Document` must be imported